# parsing google search results I get the wrong one

Tags: php, search, curl, simple-html-dom

I have such a code with cURL and Simple Html Dom Parser:

```
$ch = curl_init ("");

$query="Electrician+in+".$_GET['city_name'] (this variable = Moscow (for example));

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$query);
echo "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$query;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($output, true, false);

$k = 0;

foreach ($html->find('li.g') as $li) 
{
    if($k<4)
    {
        echo $li.'<br>';
         $k++;
    } else {
        ?>
            <div class="extra_result">
                <? echo $li.'<br>';?>
            </div>
        <?
    }
}
```

then I need to show only first 4 results, if the user clicks on button, he will see extra_result...

BUT the question is: when I input such an query in browser I get the valid results, but when I use it on my web-site - I get results like these:

```
2pac shakur

eminem

pets
```

and so on, I have never queried them, I just can't get it!

I'll appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609962/having-trouble-using-curl-and-php-to-get-google-search-results-through-a-proxy

Comment: @Ushakov Nik, I'm sorry, but how can I do that so? I googled for the "Google Search API", but nothing works now...couldn't you help me? thank you!